# Python - pyinstaller : Read path file inside script to use in pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pyinstaller

**I have script and work fine but after executable script by pyinstaller the scripte can't able to read file chromedriver.exe:**

**This is the module code:**

fulpath of `data.py`is: app\Resources\Data.py # the name app is root of script

name module `data.py`:

```
class General():

    chrome_path = "drivers\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe"

    CHROME = chrome_path
```

I use CHROME function in another module to run script.

Full path of `chromedriver.exe` is : app\drivers\chrome\chromedriver.exe # the name app is root of script.

**this is the app.spec:**

```
block_cipher = None

added_files = [
    ('driver/chrome/chromedriver.exe','driver/chrome/')
    ]

a = Analysis(['app.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\JOHN\\Desktop\\project'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='app',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          uac_admin=True,
          icon='data\\image\\icon.ico')
```

How can I change path to compatible by pyinstaller

Comment: you must start by using forward slash `/` or double backslash \\

Comment: I use \\ all fine but after convert script to .exe by pyinstaller nothing work

Comment: What is the base path? One time try giving the absolute path and see. something like "C:/Program Filese/Chrome/drivers/chrome/chromedriver.exe"

Comment: You did not put "drivers" as the folder name in your app.spec as you indicated in your source file. Try change it to "drivers" instead of "driver"

Answer (score 1):

When you call pyinstaller to build the executable, you can use `--add-data "drivers/chrome/chromedriver.exe;drivers/chrome"` as a flag to add whatever you want to the build, as seen [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files).